# My wireless adapter is not functioning

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wireless-adapter

I have a Dell latitude e5250 and I've had a lot of wireless connection problems with it lately. And now it doesn't even give me an option to connect to wifi as it says that my wireless adapter is not installed. I could use wifi just fine a week ago. The adapter also has dissapeared from "device manager". I don't really know what to do, can anyone help?

Comment: download the [driver]https://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER03602139M/1/Network_Driver_PX32H_WN32_18.40.0.9_A19.EXE from dell and try installing it. Does it show in device manager now?

Comment: Sounds like you WiFi adapter is faulty/dead, try a replacement. As-is this question is too broad, and shows a lack of research effort.

Answer (score 0):

To make your Wi-Fi connection back on, you can try this link steps...

http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-fix-windows-8-1-wi-fi-issues/

I hope this helps!!